# Running code inside gdb debugger

Tags: c, gdb

Is it possible to run code inside gdb? For example, if I were debugging a .c file, and I wanted to get the strlen() of a character array at a particular point in time, I can't just type in strlen(str) into the buffer - it is an invalid command. What can I do?

Comment: You could try using the print command, I am not sure if it allows you to call arbitrary functions though

Comment: Not only is it possible (in most cases), you can even set and hit breakpoints inside code you explicitly evaluate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From gdb prompt call strlen(the_char_array). Eg.,

```
(gdb) call strlen(the_char_array)
```